# qemu-system-aarch64: error while loading state for instance 0x0 of device 'goldfish_pipe'

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-source

I am compiling the android source, below is the script I used to initialize:

```
mkdir /var/www/android

cd /var/www/android

export USE_CCACHE=1
ccache -M 90G

repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest
repo sync

. build/envsetup.sh
lunch aosp_arm-eng
USE_CCACHE=1 CCACHE_DIR=ccache make -j$(nproc --all)
```

The command I am using to run the emulator:

```
ANDROID_BUILD_OUT=/var/www/android/out
ANDROID_SDK_LINUX=/opt/android-studio/sdk
ANDROID_BUILD=${ANDROID_BUILD_OUT}/target/product/generic

sudo chmod -R 777 /dev/kvm

lunch aosp_arm-eng

source build/envsetup.sh

set_stuff_for_environment

./prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/emulator \
    -debug-init -logcat '*:v' -verbose \
    -sysdir ${ANDROID_BUILD} \
    -system ${ANDROID_BUILD}/system.img \
    -ramdisk ${ANDROID_BUILD}/ramdisk.img \
    -data ${ANDROID_BUILD}/userdata.img \
    -partition-size 2000 \
    -memory 2000 \
```

The error displaying is:

emulator: WARNING: Couldn't find crash service executable /var/www/android/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/emulator64-crash-service

emulator: WARNING: no SD Card image at 'sdcard.img'

emulator: WARNING: encryption is off

Warning: QApplication: invalid style override passed, ignoring it.
    Available styles: Windows, Fusion ((null):0, (null))

INFO: QtLogger.cpp:66: Warning: QApplication: invalid style override 
passed, ignoring it.
    Available styles: Windows, Fusion ((null):0, (null))

qemu-system-aarch64: error while loading state for instance 0x0 of device 'goldfish_pipe'

deleteSnapshot: for default_boot

Answer (score 0):

I spent days trying to find the solution to this problem, but I could not solve the black screen problem.

But at least it will help someone with a similar problem.

Leave the review to see if it was useful to someone.

```
ANDROID_BUILD_OUT=/var/www/android/out
ANDROID_SDK_LINUX=/opt/android-studio/sdk
ANDROID_BUILD=${ANDROID_BUILD_OUT}/target/product/generic

sudo chmod -R 777 /dev/kvm

source build/envsetup.sh

lunch qemu_trusty_arm64-userdebug

set_stuff_for_environment

USE_CCACHE=1 CCACHE_DIR=ccache make -j$(nproc --all)

./prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/emulator \
    -show-kernel \
    -sysdir ${ANDROID_BUILD} \
    -system ${ANDROID_BUILD}/system.img \
    -ramdisk ${ANDROID_BUILD}/ramdisk.img \
    -data ${ANDROID_BUILD}/userdata.img \
    -kernel ./prebuilts/qemu-kernel/x86_64/kernel-qemu \
    -partition-size 2000 \
    -memory 2000 \
    -sdcard sdcard.img \
```